# How to access PHP with the Command Line on Windows?

Tags: php, command-line, command-line-interface

I am trying to learn how to access PHP scripts from the command line (CLI)

Below is an image from my attempt, please help.  I am running Windows 7

[image: Cli]

Answer (score 95, accepted):

You need to add your PHP installation directory to the `%PATH%` environment variable, or work from the PHP installation directory.

To add it to path (The best approach - *Edited for Windows 7*):

- Right-click on a `My Computer` icon
- Click `Properties`
- Click `Advanced system settings` from the left nav
- Click `Advanced` tab
- Click `Environment Variables` button
- In the `System Variables` section, select `Path` (case-insensitive) and click `Edit` button
- Add a semi-colon (`;`) to the end of the string, then add the full file system path of your PHP installation (e.g. `C:\Program Files\PHP`)
- Keep clicking `OK` etc until all dialog boxes have disappeared
- Close your command prompt and open it again
- Sorted

Alternatively, you can run `cd <PHP installation path>` before you try and run you command, or call your script like `<FULL file system path of php.exe> <path to script>`

Comment: On **Windows 8**: Press WIN + Q, enter "environ" and choose the first entry "Edit the system environment variables", saves you some mouse clicks. Proceed at step 5.

Comment: It's also worth noting that on all versions of Windows you can open the system properties dialog (first two steps) by hitting Win + pause/break

Comment: I tried this on windows 10 and it said php.exe not reconized, are there any other steps i need to take?

Comment: @DustinPoissant are you sure you tried to use it in a new command prompt? You can type `set path` in a command prompt to inspect the current value of the `%path%` environment variable and check that the installation path of PHP is present in that session

Comment: I restarted my computer and it work. Apparently with windows 10 after you add something to the PATH you have to restart sometimes.

Answer (score 13):

For temporary use, try this: (benefit for use `npm` or `composer`)

```
> SET PATH=c:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.29\;%PATH%
```

For test use this:

```
> echo %PATH%
c:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.29\;c:\anothers\;
```

Now you can access to `PHP` command:

```
> php -v
PHP 5.3.29 (cli)
```

Comment: this trick works on my PHP 8.0 and PHP 7.4

Answer (score 6):

Easy Way: Run CMD then type

```
C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.3\php.exe -f "C:\wamp\www\timenow.php"
```

Change the last part for a different script, and make sure you have the same version php folder as I do. (php5.4.3)

Comment: Life saver. Thank you :)

Answer (score 4):

On 2020 and with Windows 10 there's an easier way to achieve this.

1- Download composer at https://getcomposer.org/Composer-Setup.exe

2- Install it as you install any program on windows and (important) when it asks you the path to PHP, browse thru the correct path (for example: c:/wamp/bin/php.exe)

FINNISHED! Close the cmd and reopen and you can run PHP on your command line and also COMPOSER (composer is actually very needed if you use PHP)

Answer (score 0):

you can run cd  before you try and run you command, or call your script like