# how to run a php command using python? and how do I run php commands in command line?

Tags: php, python

I want to execute php commands using a python code. So also I wanted to know how to use php commands in command line

Comment: What you have tried so far ?

Comment: ya but I couldn't find anything

Comment: What do you mean by php Commands ? or you want to run php script ?

Comment: Please split this up into 1 questions in future. This will help you to get better answers.

Comment: This should have been two separate questions (and I bet they're both duplicates).

Answer (score 3):

With python

```
import subprocess

# if the script don't need output.
subprocess.call("php /path/to/your/script.php")

# if you want output
proc = subprocess.Popen("php /path/to/your/script.php", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
script_response = proc.stdout.read()
```

With console

```
php -r "echo 'a';"
```

Or

```
php "path\to\php\file";
```

If you are using windows, you need add php folder to PATH. View tutorial at here

[How to access PHP with the Command Line on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7307548/how-to-access-php-with-the-command-line-on-windows)

Comment: can you please explain the code for python-php with an example

Comment: You can run php script from python by using subprocess.Popen function. That is same function exec in php.

Comment: can you please explain with an example?

Comment: I had tried the code you have posted above but that's giving an error

Comment: My answer is example. Seem don't have anything to explain.

Comment: Can you post error in here?

Comment: syntax error ***invalid\x escape

Comment: Not sure about your problem, But I think this code have no problem.

Comment: but anyway please try subprocess.call(["php", "path/to/script.php"]);

Comment: how do you do the path to script pls tell with an eg

Comment: you are using linux or windows? Example
Linux: /var/www/script.php
Windows: C:\\htdocs\\www\\script.php

Comment: I am using windows my script name is omsha.php  that script is stored in c drive then xampp then htdocs then a folder DONE in the folder DONE there is the script named omsha.php   Pls tell the entire format to write

Comment: import subprocess

subprocess.call("php C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\DONE\\omsha.php")