# Command php not found in Windows

Tags: php

I have installed xampp server in windows 7. I have already checked Browser its working.But I am trying to run the php -v command prompt.  I receive the following error message.

```
´php´ is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file
```

Comment: Add the path to your `php.exe` to your `PATH` environment variable

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7307548/how-to-access-php-with-the-command-line-on-windows.

Comment: In your command prompt, first enter the path to the folder with php.exe like `c:\php\php -v`.

Comment: @sripriya Please take a look at the answer in the question I linked above. It shows you what you need to do.

Comment: thank u @hRdCoder working good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This pops up if Windows doesnt know about `php`. To solve this you have to add the full path to the php.exe to your `PATH`-variable in windows.

After you restart the console php should be available.

Answer (score 2):

Add the php folder to your path and restart cmd.

Use this command from the command line (use the path to the php.exe, it is usually under `c:\xampp\php`):

```
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\xampp\php
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the full path to find the folder, for example:
c:\xampp\php\php.exe -v or c:\xampp\php\php.exe -version