# Symfony2 - app/console

Tags: php, symfony

I am a beginner with Symfony and the command line.
Within the command lines I cannot go into app / console...

My Symfony project is located in a "Symfony-2.4" folder in my www folder (wamp path),

I typed this into the CLI

**cd c:\wamp\www\Symfony-2.4**

And I get this:

**php app/console**

But nothing is displayed in my command line, Why ?

Image:
https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/sdz-upload/prod/upload/Sans%20titre-1100.png

Comment: Please response in add a comment and not answers. The answer must be apport a solution at your problem.

Comment: Ok. sory. I will be for next time

Answer (score 1):

You must learn how use command line before trying to learn Symfony2.

`app/console` is a PHP script. For use it, you must use arguments, like :

`app/console server:run` for run PHP built-in server.

`app/console cache:clear` for clear cache.

And a lot of others you can find in [Symfony2 Official Documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/index.html)

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Please read the symfony requirements documentation. http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/requirements.html

Firstly, you can execute **php app/check.php** to analyse your configuration.

Comment: for: php app/check.php. I have this http://www.creerwebsite.com/medias/upload/c1.png

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you can access PHP from the command prompt. To check this , type 
`php --version`
in the command prompt. If this command returns the php version, then you're good to go. Otherwise, you would need to add the path to your PHP executable file in your `%PATH%` environment variable. The steps to do so are explained in detail in this question [How to access PHP with the Command Line on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7307548/how-to-access-php-with-the-command-line-on-windows)