# How to run php code on command prompt using xampp

Tags: php

hey I want to run php on command prompt with xampp server. I made 2 environmental variables C:\xampp\php and C:\xampp\mysql\bin. how to execute the php code now?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access PHP with the Command Line on Windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7307548/how-to-access-php-with-the-command-line-on-windows)

Answer (score 5):

Run command from console

```
c:\xampp\<path to php>\php.exe <path_to_your_php_project>\your_script.php
```

Comment: Even better - add the path to PHP to your system path

Comment: yes. i can execute it now. but i have one more php file in which i have html code and php tag also. but when i execute that php file then i am getting html code as output in cmd. How can i solve this error?

Comment: But why you trying to call script from console which generate HTML?

Comment: actually i have file upload code in html in which i am uploading photos and storing it in a folder on server.

Comment: Why you trying to do it from console?

Comment: i am trying to learn the php from all aspect and i have heard that if we want to make client-server app then server code have to run through cmd.

Comment: can i run html from console?

Comment: Yes, you can. For this purpose usually create a file what produces output with text formated for console. For example, `<?php echo "Begin...\n"; someCommand(); echo "Finish\n";`