# Composer json does not contain valid JSON

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, runtime-error

Hello I am trying to use laravel but i fail with the installation of composer.

I am using a windows 7 and when I install the setup of composer there is not any problem. The problem come when I use the comand `composer -V` it return to me [these error](http://prntscr.com/cc25nx).

I do not undestand what it means. if someone can explain to me the error.
Thanks for read it. And sorry if there are some post like these but where i could read i do not undesrtand nothing.

Comment: It would probably help if you posted your composer.json file.

Comment: As I understand your question: Have you have recently installed composer in you Windows 7?

Comment: How did you install Composer? `C:\xampp\php\php.exe` _shouldn't_ contain valid JSON… that's your PHP interpreter. (Also, in the future please copy error messages _as text_ directly into your question instead of linking to a screenshot.)

Answer (score 1):

paste composer.json file on a validator and it should point out the syntax error

try http://www.jsonlint.com

Comment: How can i know where is the json?

Comment: @mohamet-monte I hadn't looked at your error image ... this is different ... I'm not sure but maybe the composer.json file in your project root

Comment: navigate into www/laravel and you'll find composer.json

Comment: I do no start the project, beacuse on the video i see they install first composer

Comment: then something is wrong with your composer installation ... I don't know what it is

Answer (score 0):

It returns the error:

```
Parse error on line 1:
MZ
^
Expecting one of: 'String', 'Number', 'Null' ... {', '['
```

Kindly check your entire JSON must start from '{' and end from '}' so your invalid JSON convert into Valid JSON.

Copy your JSON into this website: http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: I dont know where is the json.

Comment: Kindly check your composer.json file.

Comment: I do not have any composer.json on the directory

Comment: In Laravel you don't have composer.json file ? How it is possible ?

Comment: I did not dowload laravel yet. I am istalling composer first like on the video of youtube

Answer (score 0):

First make sure that you can use `php` on your command line. You can run:

```
php -v
```

This should give you the php version. If not, add the php executable to your windows path file (https://stackoverflow.com/a/7307581/1354222).

Run this in your bash window, in the laravel folder, to get the latest composer version (installation instructions are from the composer website):

```
php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"
php -r "if (hash_file('SHA384', 'composer-setup.php') === 'aa96f26c2b67226a324c27919f1eb05f21c248b987e6195cad9690d5c1ff713d53020a02ac8c217dbf90a7eacc9d141d') { echo 'Installer verified'; } else { echo 'Installer corrupt'; unlink('composer-setup.php'); } echo PHP_EOL;"
php composer-setup.php
php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');"
```

Then use the following command to install laravel (from the laravel website, slightly adapted for your situation):

```
php composer.phar create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog
```

Answer (score 0):

try update you vendor/composer/installer.json to following.

```
{}
```

this same happened to me