# Error Magento supports PHP 5.6, 7.0.2, and 7.0.6 or later

Tags: php, magento, version, magento2

I am new to magento Developing.
When I issue command like `php bin/magento --clear-static-content module:enable Training_Test` using windows CLI, 
I am given following Error:-
 "

> Magento supports PHP 5.6, 7.0.2, and 7.0.6 or later

"

When I installed Magento, My Wamp had php version's 5.6.25 and 7.0.10 and I have magento 2.1.
after I got the error, I also installed php versions 7.0.2 and 7.0.6, but still I am getting same error.

Comment: what is the output of `php -v` ?

Comment: php 5.5.12...how do I upgrade php in cli??

Comment: Check if the command `php7` exists instead of `php`. If it does not work, you have to find where is the php 7 executable from wamp and change your path variable to point to the php7 directory. Have a look here : [How to access PHP with the Command Line on Windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7307581/3992945)