# Rachet Server not Starting

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to start rachet server in codeignitor via command prompt put I keep getting an error. Any advice? I have attached the command screenshot.

Here is the command screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Make sure you have added the path to PHP in Windows PATH environment variable. Remember that you will need to close and open a new cmd after it's done.

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7307548/how-to-access-php-with-the-command-line-on-windows - There might be some slight differences depending on what Windows version you're using.