# Can I start cmd and do some commands with php?

Tags: php, ocr

I am just starting to build an Android app using `Tesseract` to detect the text. My idea is to put the image process part to a server built on `PHP`. But to start `Tesseract` on my Windows laptop, it needs `CMD`. I am not a web developer and am new with `PHP`; as far as I have searched on the internet, `PHP` cant do this kind of task. But is there any way around?

*This is not a duplicate, it is not about how to access PHP from CMD, please read carefully before flagging as a duplicate.*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access PHP with the Command Line on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7307548/how-to-access-php-with-the-command-line-on-windows)

Comment: Which command you want to execute from PHP?

Comment: i just need to do something like this: tesseract test_image.png output
it mean to create a txt file contain the text in the input image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can execute any Windows Command from PHP like this:

```
$output = shell_exec("getmac");
```

Instead of `getmac` you can put any valid windows command which can be executed from Command-line.