# Composer installation

Tags: laravel

I updated a lower version of my local server to the required one while installing composer but I get this error [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CFIZg.png)

Comment: Your question is unclear, without a clear and well thought out question you're unlikely to get a clear and well thought out answer. Please review the SO [guide on asking good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and have a quick read of [this blog post](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/) which contains a checklist of actions to take before asking a question.

Answer (score 0):

From your screenshot, looks like Windows doesn't recognize php.

Try adding php to your PATH variable. 
Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7307548/how-to-access-php-with-the-command-line-on-windows)